# TagNames is always empty when retrieving note using ENNoteStoreClient

Tags: c#, evernote

I'm developing an application that utilizes the Evernote API using the SDK for C#.

Using the EDAM API, when I call `ENNoteStoreClient.GetNote()`, the TagGuids list is get populated but TagNames does not.

Is there a way to retrieve the TagNames for a note without an extra API call (`GetNoteTagNames` for example)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get both the note content and the note tag textual names in the same roundtrip using the EDAM API. You'll have to make another roundtrip using the [getNoteTagNames](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteTagNames) method and supplying it with the note GUID you are interested in.

(If you are populating a UI with lots of notes and tags, consider keeping a local cache of the mappings between tag GUIDs and names to prevent some roundtrips. You could, say, prepopulate a local cache with [listTags](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags) once, and then later if you see a GUID you don't recognize, call `getNoteTagNames`, or flush the cache and get the new set on the account.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have implemented the caching route to minimize calls to the API.  Thanks again